# How to tell ProGuard to obfuscate method and class names?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using ProGuard to obfuscate my apk, but there's no changes in class and method names - they are same as before. Only variable names are changed.

Most of them doesn't extends classes like Activity; there's some inheritance in my code, but it's 100% written by myself.

I'm using d2j-dex2jar and jd-gui to check results.

Some of classes are excluded because of GSON usage, here is my proguard-project.txt:

```
-keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
-dontwarn com.google.ads.** # Temporary workaround for v6.2.1. It gives a warning that you can ignore

# Add any classes the interact with gson
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.PlayerData
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.SettingsDescriptor
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.ShipStatus
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.descriptors.ShipDescriptor
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.descriptors.Ships
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.game.galaxies.Galaxies

-keep public class com.badlogic.** {*;}



##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: have you enabled proguard in release mode?. Also you can extract the files from apk and check whether your java files are obfuscated

Comment: i'm guessing yes, because there are obfuscated variable names, so proguard is running

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have this problem with Components (Activity, Services or BroadcastReceivers) classes then this is OK.

Proguard doesn't obfuscate the names of Components.

---

And if you are taking about the classes which defined as

```
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.PlayerData
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.SettingsDescriptor
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.playerdata.ShipStatus
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.descriptors.ShipDescriptor
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.descriptors.Ships
-keep class com.revicostudio.gravityrun.game.galaxies.Galaxies
```

ALSO their name can not be changed, because of `keep` option.

---

Make a try with removing `-keep public class * { public protected *; }` line

Comment: There's one Activity for AndEngine, and it's almost all. Rest of classes are 100% custom.

Comment: Those classes can't be obfuscated because of GSON serialization, but there's a lot of other classes that should be obfuscated and they're not - those ones which contains logic part of game

Comment: OK. Right. Make a try with removing `-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}` line...

Comment: Okey, now they're obfuscated. I need to add some more excludes and everything should work good.

Comment: In Android action bar,adding menu item in action bar method should be excluded. I have tried excluding the AddMenuItem methods class, but still the menu item is not displayed in the obfuscated jar file. How can I achieve obfuscation without affecting the class and method for Action Bar Menu. In the below link specifies have to exclude the method. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Answer (score 2):

Some time class name obfuscation don't work cause of "butterknife"
So add below rules in your proguard file.

```
# Butterknife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class butterknife.** { *; } 
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.InjectView <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.OnClick <methods>;
    @butterknife.OnEditorAction <methods>;
    @butterknife.OnItemClick <methods>;
    @butterknife.OnItemLongClick <methods>;
    @butterknife.OnLongClick <methods>;
}
```

NOTE: Use above rules only when you are using "butterknife".

Answer (score 1):

Butterknife's old instructions defined code for proguard causes this issue, if you are using butterknife and an older version like version 7, make sure you don't have this line in your proguared rules

```
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.Bind *;}
```

This is causing all class names not be to obfuscated.

Use below config for butterknife, is better and future proof compare to another suggestion.

```
# ButterKnife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```